# influxdb failed cause spring application run failed

Tags: java, spring, influxdb, reconnect

I use spring auto-configure to connect influxdb in a spring boot command line application.

the application will run failed, when influxdb is  suddenly down.

I `Autowired` the Influxdb instance in Application, and when inflxudb is down, my application runs failed.

I didn't find any information about reconnecting to influxdb in influx-java or spring auto-configure.

How should I config to  reconnect to the influxdb?

Comment: influx-db use okhttp to connect to influxdb, maybe it doesn't need to reconnect?

Comment: Then how I can recovery from the failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't paster your code, but I think if your db connection faild cause your spring application failed, it usually means, you did NOT catch all of your exception and throw to upper level, and at last spring framework can't handle the exception and run failed.

So check your code around the database action, and catch all the exception, I think , at least, your spring application will not failed.

If you have any question, please show us your code.